# GDAL crashes with segmentation fault when trying to open a NetCDF subdataset with time dimension

Tags: gdal, netcdf, xarray

I am trying to create a NetCDF file which is compliant with the NetCDF Conventions CF-1.4.

The dimensions of the file are `(TIME, Y, X)` where Y and X are the polar stereographic grid.

The file that I generate contains three variables: `runoff (TIME, Y, X)`, `lat (Y, X)` and `lon (Y, X)`. With gdalinfo I can access lat and lon, but not runoff:

```
$ gdalinfo NETCDF:"myfile.nc":runoff
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In other words it looks like the `TIME` dimension is causing problems. I've tried writing all the data in the `runoff` attribute as zeroes but that didn't help.

The file was created using xarray, with output set to `NETCDF4`. The `ncdump` of the file is as follows. Is there anything strange about it that might be causing GDAL to have problems?

```
netcdf myfile {
dimensions:
    X = 756 ;
    TIME = 12 ;
    Y = 786 ;
variables:
    int64 X(X) ;
        X:units = "meters" ;
        X:standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate" ;
        X:point_spacing = "even" ;
        X:axis = "X" ;
    int64 TIME(TIME) ;
        TIME:standard_name = "time" ;
        TIME:axis = "TIME" ;
        TIME:units = "days since 1958-01-01 00:00:00" ;
        TIME:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
    int64 Y(Y) ;
        Y:units = "meters" ;
        Y:standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate" ;
        Y:point_spacing = "even" ;
        Y:axis = "Y" ;
    double runoff(TIME, Y, X) ;
        runoff:_FillValue = -9999. ;
        runoff:long_name = "runoff" ;
        runoff:units = "mmWE" ;
        runoff:standard_name = "runoff" ;
        runoff:grid_mapping = "polar_stereographic" ;
    double lon(Y, X) ;
        lon:_FillValue = -9999. ;
        lon:grid_mapping = "polar_stereographic" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_west" ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
    byte polar_stereographic ;
        polar_stereographic:grid_mapping_name = "polar_stereographic" ;
        polar_stereographic:scale_factor_at_central_origin = 0. ;
        polar_stereographic:standard_parallel = 70. ;
        polar_stereographic:straight_vertical_longitude_from_pole = -45. ;
        polar_stereographic:latitude_of_projection_origin = 90. ;
        polar_stereographic:false_easting = 0. ;
        polar_stereographic:false_northing = 0. ;
    double lat(Y, X) ;
        lat:_FillValue = -9999. ;
        lat:grid_mapping = "polar_stereographic" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;

// global attributes:
        :Conventions = "CF-1.4" ;
        :history = "redacted" ;
        :institution = "redacted" ;
        :title = "redacted" ;
        :source = "redacted" ;
        :proj4 = "+init=epsg:3413" ;
        :nx = 756. ;
        :ny = 786. ;
        :xmin = -1790000. ;
        :ymax = -65000. ;
        :spacing = 5000.
```

Comment: GDAL should never produce segmentation fault so I think that you have found some sort of bug. I would write to gdal-dev mailing list and provide a link to test data.

Comment: Thanks @user30184. I'll submit a GDAL bug report and post any follow up here.

Comment: Nice bug report and the fix came in the same evening https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6870.

Answer (score 4):

The problem turned out to be a bug in GDAL, which is now fixed: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6870.